Manipulate struct data vertically
I have a function that takes three structs and list of widgets. I want to link all of these widgets with particular field in struct and then process accordingly.
struct SomeStruct { QString first; QString second; QString third; ... };
void manipulateData(const QList<SomeObject*>& list, const SomeStruct& a, const SomeStruct& b, const SomeStruct& c)
{
   
}

What I could do, is just have boilerplate code in the form:
list[0]->setValue(a.first);
list[0]->setData(b.first + c.first);
list[1]->setValue(a.second);
list[1]->setData(b.second + c.second);
... (maybe more for each)

But I am trying to do it a bit better, so my initial idea is to create a list of structs with form that is comfortable to use:
void manipulateData(const QList<SomeObject*>& list, const SomeStruct& a, const SomeStruct& b, const SomeStruct& c)
{
struct TempStruct { SomeObject* obj; QString a; QString b; QString c; };
QList<TempStruct> tempList = {
 {list[0], a.first, b.first, c.first},
 {list[1], a.second, b.second, c.second},
 ...
}
for(const auto& item: tempList)
{
 item.obj->setValue(item.a);
 item.obj->setData(item.b + item.c);
}
}

This way this is easier to add new row to my list of structs.
The problem I still have, is it still doesn't feel like the best idea, since I have to repeat words `a.first, b.first, c.first'. What would be enough, is to populate it with some kind of 'way' to retrieve 'first', 'second', 'third' in struct 'SomeStruct'. So in the end, I would like my structure to look (and be populated) somehow like this:
void manipulateData(const QList<SomeObject*>& list, const SomeStruct& a, const SomeStruct& b, const SomeStruct& c)
{
struct TempStruct { SomeObject* obj; int getter}; //not sure about the type of getter
QList<TempStruct> tempList = {
 {list[0], &a.first - &a}, //diff in memory place?
 {list[1], &a.second - &a},
 ...
}
for(const auto& item: tempList)
{
 item.obj->setValue(*(&a+item.getter));
 item.obj->setData(*(&b+item.getter) + *(&c+item.getter));
}
}

I am not sure about types in my last example (consider it a pseudocode) - I have two questions:

Is it safe to assume, that &c + &(b.second)-&b=&(c.second) ?
Is there a better solution, maybe more clear?

I've included some explanation about question 1 (is my understanding is correct?)


Is it safe to assume, that &c + &(b.second)-&b=&(c.second) ? -- No it is not safe.  You cannot add (or subtract) addresses from two different variables.  Do not assume because the variables appear one after the other in the code that the addresses are "contiguous" in some way.

@PaulMcKenzie What about &c + (&(b.second)-&b) = &(c.second)?
Of course, assuming c and b are same type.
How I understand it, is that &(b.second)-&b is the difference between address of struct itself (&b) and address of it's member second (&b.second) - this way I thought, the difference is not-dependent on particular object, but only on type - and applying the same difference to other object (c) will give me same member (second)

@PaulMcKenzie I've added picture how I understand it - I don't think I made an assumption that addresses of two structs are contigious - but that addresses within struct are - which may of course be totally wrong! :) (that's why the question)

... (maybe more for each) -- Let's see what list[2] looks like, and maybe list[3].  Right now, you have first, second, but it isn't clear what third, fourth, fifth, etc. will be.  And if these are the same type, why not use an array of type T instead of individual fields?

List is just a list of pointers to widgets (I tried to simplify the example, as it IMO doesn't matter) - QLineEdit* which would have tooltip and text and some properties set based on the structs (that's why dummy functions setData and setValue). Each of these widget is supposed to be linked to particular field in the struct to simplify operations. For now, struct members ( first, second, ... ) are mostly QString, but with possibility to make more complex types (it's data about device - type, name, ID etc) - when I add more complex types, they'd all still have .toString() method

That's why the name of the question there - looking at it without technical details, it is pretty much a 2D structure with [[a.x, a.y, a.z], [b.x, b.y, b.z], [c.x, c.y, c.z]] that I want to transform into a 2D structure looking like this: [[a.x, b.x, c.x], [a.y, b.y, c.y], [a.z, b.z, c.z]] -- (in this interpretation, I consider a struct a list of member values)

You are looking for a way to map a class instance to one of its members. This is exactly what a pointer to member is for. It is the well-defined way to express your &a.first-&a provided by the language. The language also provides the offsetof macro, but for your use case, pointer to member is the best-suited tool.
void manipulateData(const QList<SomeObject*>& list, const SomeStruct& a, const SomeStruct& b, const SomeStruct& c)
{
struct TempStruct { SomeObject* obj; int SomeStruct::* getter};
QList<TempStruct> tempList = {
 {list[0], &SomeStruct::first},
 {list[1], &SomeStruct::second},
 //...
}
for(const auto& item: tempList)
{
 item.obj->setValue(a.*(item.getter));
 item.obj->setData(b.*(item.getter) + c.*(item.getter));
}
}

The parentheses around item.getter are not strictly needed according to the precedence (so a.*item.getter would also work). They are only included for clarity.

I've found a solution, not sure if this is the best and I am still open for better answers or upgrading this answer. Instead of having getter as a difference of addresses (as in last example), I used lambda functions.
void manipulateData(const QList<SomeObject*>& list, const SomeStruct& a, const SomeStruct& b, const SomeStruct& c)
{
struct TempStruct { SomeObject* obj; std::function<QString(SomeStruct)> fun}; //return type can be also variant type or just pointer to field (any type), would require to be cast later
QList<TempStruct> tempList = {
 {list[0], [](const SomeStruct& s) { return s.first; }}, 
 {list[1], [](const SomeStruct& s) { return s.second; }},
 ...
}
for(const auto& item: tempList)
{
 item.obj->setValue(item.fun(a));
 item.obj->setData(item.fun(b) + item.fun(c));
}
}


